# Updating Android SDK Manager shutsdown the system on Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, amd-processor

**My System:**

- AMD 4 core
- 8 GB memory
- 120 GB SSD
- Ubuntu 64  bit
- Android Studio

On Android Studio, I was trying to update the SDK via the Android SDK Manager and after 1-2 mins while downloading the system automatically shut down.

This has happened consistently and happens only during update of SDK Manager.
I am suspecting that it is shutting down the system because some of the PC component is getting hot. But not sure which one and if there is any other reason.

I also checked the CPU usage and memory usage and it was at around 30 % usage for both CPU and memory.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it was shutting down was because my computer was heating up and it did not have very good cooling fans and i had left the case open.

I got a new case with good cooling system and it has been 1 month and has never shutdown and the Temperature has gone down from 65 deg C to 30 deg C.

Hope this will help others as well.